# Nested models' views with Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, models, rails-geocoder

I'm trying to make a simple app that records your trips. In should get two locations (via nested model) and then show distance between them in /show~
Unfortunately, I can make a new trip, but I can't get the view for the distance. However, if I want to put 'location.address' it doesn't work too.

trip controller:

```
def index
  @trips = Trip.all
  @trip = Trip.new
  2.times do
    location = @trip.locations.build
  end
end

def show
  @trip = Trip.includes(:locations).find(params[:id])
end
```

location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip

  extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

end
```

trip model:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

show view for trips:

```
<% for location in @trip.locations %>
  <li><%= location.distance %></li>
<% end %>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Edit:
Ok, so I found how to calculate distance between specific places, but I don't know how to add two locations from one nested model to this code?:

```
@distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([place1], [place2])
```

Comment: Would you please fix the indentation?

Comment: Edited (best as I can, I'm a beginner)

Comment: You have a syntax error in the TripController#index method - you are missing an `end`.

Comment: Geocoder works out the distance.  You'd need to use `.near` method it provides to get the distance.

Comment: @japed but how to use .near to find a distance between these two locations?

Comment: You might be able to just put the locations in place of place1 and place 2.  If not you'd need to get the lat and long for each in an array and put that in as per Geocoder's examples in the documentation

Comment: @japed Yeah, that's work with two places, but how to put two locations from nested model here?

Comment: Exactly how I said, pass in the locations.

Comment: @japed Could you please write the code for it here, please? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `@distance = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(@trip.locations.first(2))` might work.  Otherwise create a method returning the latitude and longitude on the location model and pass that in instead

Comment: @japed The bad thing is I can't even show these locations in view - I mean they're not even saving when I create new trip?

Comment: That is a different question.  Can you post all your code for creating trips.  Controller, and Views, and any validations that could prevent saving.